# Update values in dataframe from a reference data frame, based on matching of a second variable

Tags: r

I have two data frames in R which look like these.

```
> df
    Var1 Freq
1   0.01    1
2      1   27
3    100   27
4   1000  488
5   2000    4
6   5000    7
7  50000    7
8 100000    1


> return_matrix
         Var1 Freq
1     0.00001    0
2        0.01    0
3           1    0
4           8    0
5         100    0
6         200    0
7         500    0
8        1000    0
9        2000    0
10       5000    0
11      10000    0
12      50000    0
13     100000    0
14     200000    0
15     500000    0
16    1000000    0
17   10000000    0
18  100000000    0
19 1000000000    0
```

I wanted to do like a Vlookup kind of stuff of the above data frames so that the output will look like below:

```
  > combined
             Var1 Freq
    1     0.00001    0
    2        0.01    1
    3           1   27
    4           8    0
    5         100   27
    6         200    0
    7         500    0
    8        1000  488
    9        2000    4
    10       5000    7
    11      10000    0
    12      50000    7
    13     100000    1
    14     200000    0
    15     500000    0
    16    1000000    0
    17   10000000    0
    18  100000000    0
```

I tried to perform a merge in R using the below mentioned R code. However i am not getting the expected results like above. Could you please help me on this?

```
> combined_matrix <- merge(return_matrix, df, by = "Var1" )
> combined_matrix
    Var1 Freq.x Freq.y
1   0.01      0      1
2      1      0     27
3    100      0     27
4   1000      0    488
5 100000      0      1
6   2000      0      4
7   5000      0      7
8  50000      0      7
```

Comment: Add `all=T` as argument for the merge, this will keep all rows from both data.frames. Then you can do `combined_matrix$Freq <- combined_matrix$Freq.x+combined_matrix$Freq.y` and you're done (you can drop Freq.x and Freq.y by setting them to NULL).

Comment: that still drops every row not present in df though, doesn't it?

Comment: @antoine-sac - This has worked. However I want the numbers displayed in Var1 of combined data frame, in the same order. Is there a way please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to merge anything here.

```
id <- match(return_matrix$Var1, df$Var1, nomatch = 0L)
return_matrix$Freq[id != 0] <- df$Freq[id]
```

does the trick.

This code will outperform any `merge` or `plyr` solution by manifold. It's about 100 times faster than `ddply` and about 10 times faster than `merge` in the following simulation on my machine:

```
library(plyr)
library(rbenchmark)
df <- data.frame(
  Var1 = c(0.01, 1, 100, 1000, 2000, 5000, 50000,100000),
  Freq = c(1,27,27,488,4,7,7,1)
)

return_matrix <- data.frame(
  Var1 = c(0.00001,0.01,1,8,100,200,500,1000,2000,5000,
           10000,50000,100000,200000,500000,1e6,1e7,1e8),
  Freq = 0
)



codeJM <- function(df, return_matrix){
  id <- match(return_matrix$Var1, df$Var1, nomatch = 0L)
  return_matrix$Freq[id != 0] <- df$Var1[id]
  return_matrix
}

codemerge <- function(df, return_matrix){
  combined_matrix <- merge(return_matrix, df, by = "Var1" , all = TRUE)
  combined_matrix$Freq <- combined_matrix$Freq.x+combined_matrix$Freq.y
  combined_matrix$Freq.x <- combined_matrix$Freq.y <- NULL
  combined_matrix
}

codeddply <- function(df, return_matrix){
  full <- rbind(df,return_matrix)
  combined <- ddply(full ,.(Var1),function(x) 
                      data.frame(Var1=x$Var1[1],Freq=sum(x$Freq)))
  combined
}

benchmark(
  codemerge(df, return_matrix),
  codeJM(df, return_matrix),
  codeddply(df, return_matrix),
  replications = 1000
)
```

gives :

```
                          test replications elapsed relative user.self 
3 codeddply(df, return_matrix)         1000    5.38    107.6      5.37        
2    codeJM(df, return_matrix)         1000    0.05      1.0      0.05        
1 codemerge(df, return_matrix)         1000    0.51     10.2      0.52
```

Comment: it gives some unexpected result. Did i miss out something? Should i post the result that i receive here?

Comment: @Arun I made a typo. Obviously the last line should be `df$Freq` instead of `df$Var1`. On a sidenote: This will outperform any merge or ddply solution by far.

Comment: This worked perfectly to the expectations. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can either work with the match function Joris suggests or use the ddply function from the plyr package:

```
library(plyr)
full <- rbind(df,return_matrix)
combined <- ddply(full ,.(Var1),function(x) data.frame(Var1=x$Var1[1],Freq=sum(x$Freq)))
```

This will sum the values from Freq even if they are not 0 in return_matrix

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.It worked. However the numbers in Var1 appears in the order mentioned in the "df". Not in the order as in "return matrix" data frame mentioned above. Is there anyway to sort that please?

Comment: What do you mean? Are both df and return_matrix not simply ordered according to the rising value of Var1? If they are not, you can simply sort the resulting array http://www.statmethods.net/management/sorting.html

Comment: @Arun There is a way: not using `ddply`. It does the reordering because it splits the full data frame based on Var1 and then does calculation on every sub-dataframe. So either you reorder the result later on in the order you want, or you use another method.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `merge` by selecting `all.x = TRUE`, this keeps all rows:

```
c<-merge(return_matrix, df, by = "Var1", all.x = TRUE)
```

This will create a second freq column, but you can clean it fairly easily

```
c<-c[, -2]
c[,2][which(is.na(c[,2]))]<- 0
```